# Button not recognized after declaration

Tags: java, android

As you can see, usually in Eclipse when buttons are working and such it'll have the blue highlighted text when you declare something to a variable.

The problem I'm having is after I declare **Button startBtn, aboutBtn;**, the variable names will always turn blue indicating that it is working. But right now, for my MainActivity.class, those variables aren't in blue at all. I've tried creating a new class and copying all over and tried doing from scratch and it did not worked. Its odd because my other java class is working fine and button variables are recognized and are highlighted in blue. Anyone has came across this?

**MainActivity.class**

```
package tp.mp2014.dotmatrix;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.Button;


    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            Button aboutBtn, startBtn;

            aboutBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.aboutBtn);
            startBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startBtn);

            aboutBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent about = new Intent(MainActivity.this, aboutPage.class);
                    startActivity(about);

                }
            });

           startBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent start = new Intent(MainActivity.this, startPage.class);
                    startActivity(start);

                }
            });
            if (savedInstanceState == null) {
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                        .commit();
            }
        }


        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        /**
         * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
         */
        public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

            public PlaceholderFragment() {
            }

            @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
                return rootView;
            }
        }

    }
```

**startPage.class**

```
package tp.mp2014.dotmatrix;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;

public class startPage extends Activity {

    Button backButton, nextButton;
    RadioGroup modechoice1, modechoice2, modechoice3, sizechoice1, sizechoice2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.selectionmode);

        nextButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextselection);
        backButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.backselection);
        modechoice1 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.textmode);
        modechoice2 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.animationmode);
        modechoice3 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.imagemode);
        sizechoice1 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.normal);
        sizechoice2 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.extended);

        /*Text Mode and 32X32 Display*/
        int choice1mode = modechoice1.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        int choice1size = sizechoice1.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

        /*Animation Mode and 32x32 Display*/
        int choice2mode = modechoice2.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        choice1size = sizechoice1.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

        if(choice1mode == 1 && choice1size == 1){

            nextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent nextSelection = new Intent(startPage.this, textmode32by32.class);
                    startActivity(nextSelection);

                }
            });

        }else if(choice2mode == 1 && choice1size == 1){

            nextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent nextSelection1 = new Intent(startPage.this, animationmode32by32.class);
                    startActivity(nextSelection1);

                }
            });

        }

        backButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent backSelection = new Intent(startPage.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(backSelection);

            }
        });




    }

}
```

**LogCat**

```
    04-29 10:19:57.820: E/AndroidRuntime(27444): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-29 10:19:57.820: E/AndroidRuntime(27444): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{tp.mp2014.dotmatrix/tp.mp2014.dotmatrix.startPage}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RadioButton cannot be cast to android.widget.RadioGroup
04-29 10:19:57.820: E/AndroidRuntime(27444):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2129)
04-29 10:19:57.820: E/AndroidRuntime(27444):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2154)
04-29 10:19:57.820: E/AndroidRuntime(27444):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:146)
04-29 10:19:57.820: E/AndroidRuntime(27444):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1260)
04-29 10:19:57.820: E/AndroidRuntime(27444):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-29 10:19:57.820: E/AndroidRuntime(27444):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-29 10:19:57.820: E/AndroidRuntime(27444):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4949)
04-29 10:19:57.820: E/AndroidRuntime(27444):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-29 10:19:57.820: E/AndroidRuntime(27444):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-29 10:19:57.820: E/AndroidRuntime(27444):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1043)
04-29 10:19:57.820: E/AndroidRuntime(27444):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:810)
04-29 10:19:57.820: E/AndroidRuntime(27444):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-29 10:19:57.820: E/AndroidRuntime(27444): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RadioButton cannot be cast to android.widget.RadioGroup
04-29 10:19:57.820: E/AndroidRuntime(27444):    at tp.mp2014.dotmatrix.startPage.onCreate(startPage.java:22)
04-29 10:19:57.820: E/AndroidRuntime(27444):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5185)
04-29 10:19:57.820: E/AndroidRuntime(27444):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
04-29 10:19:57.820: E/AndroidRuntime(27444):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2093)
04-29 10:19:57.820: E/AndroidRuntime(27444):    ... 11 more
```

**selectionmode.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1H"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textmodeselection"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/textmodeselection"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textsizeselection"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:text="@string/textsizeselection"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/textsizeselection"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/modeselection"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/modeselection" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/normal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="@string/sizechoice1" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/extended"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/sizechoice2" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/modeselection"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/LinearLayout1H" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/textmode"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="@string/modechoice1" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/animationmode"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/modechoice2" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/imagemode"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/modechoice3" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/backselection"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="@string/back" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/nextselection"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="@string/next" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your errors are caused by these lines

```
modechoice1 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.textmode);
modechoice2 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.animationmode);
modechoice3 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.imagemode);
sizechoice1 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.normal);
sizechoice2 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.extended);
```

`textmode`, `animationmode`, etc. are all `RadioButton`s defined in your xml layout. So when you are doing `(RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.textmode);`, that does not work because you cannot convert a `RadioButton` to a `RadioGroup`.

Instead get the `RadioGroup` and call `getCheckedRadioButtonId` on that:

```
RadioGroup modechoice = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.modeselection);
RadioGroup sizechoice = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.textsizeselection);

int modeChoiceId = modechoice.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
int sizeChoiceId = sizechoice.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

// An example, not sure about your logic.
if (modeChoiceId == R.id.textmode && sizeChoiceId == R.id.normal){

}
```

Also note that `getCheckedRadioButtonId` returns an ID of the selected `RadioButton`, not an index.

---

The syntax highlighting of variables do not denote whether they work or not, or whether they are recognized or not.

I believe you're referring to the differences between the syntax highlighting of a *local* or *instance* variable.

[image]

Since you defined `aboutBtn` and `startBtn` as local variables, they are not highlighted in blue, just like the variable called `local` in the image above.

If you define them like the variable `field` in the image above, they will be highlighted in blue denoting an instance variable.

All this assuming you know the difference between the two.

The image above is the syntax coloring preferences which can be found in:
Window -> Preferences - Java -> Editor -> Syntax Coloring

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't know that. Pretty new to programming still. Thanks for clearing up. Well then, that isn't the source of the problem I assumed. Right now, whenever I press the startButton, the app will crash itself. I've pasted my startPage.class to let you have a look if you may help. Thanks.

Comment: @user3558777 If you are having a crash, post the LogCat output of the Crash, there should be a block starting with "Fatal Exception...", if you add that to your OP we can start to diagnose what the problem is.

Comment: @symphony888 Can you post your xml for `selectionmode`? In `startPage` on line 22 is your error. `RadioButton` with the id of `textmode` is being converted to a `RadioGroup` hence the error.

Comment: @singularhum - Did add already. Also it is a RadioGroup which consists of RadioButtons, so I assumed that using `getCheckedRadioButtonId()` is the correct way of adding it into an IF Statement. Because if I were to use the `getChecked()`, all the button would go to the same page instead of different options going to different activities.

Comment: So are you saying, I need to rename all the `RadioGroup` in the brackets to `RadioButton`? But if I were to use RadioButton, the `getCheckedRadioButtonId()` wouldnt work

Comment: @symphony888 sorry I missed a few lines when I made the edit. Edited again. You don't need to get the radio buttons, just the radiogroup so that you can get the selected radio button.

Comment: @singularhum yeah. now I understand what you mean. new knowledge :) thanks a lot. Just to ask another question, I have 2 items that is separate. A normal textview and the radiogroup. But both the IDs keep tele-ing to be the same each other. When I change of its ID, the other will follow. Any idea why? - NEVERMIND, fixed it. Thanks

Comment: @symphony888 yeah no problem! No idea about that one sorry. You may want to ask a separate question, or see if there's anything in a search, this particular question/discussion is getting long!